# DELPHI - How to declare a procedure as argument in other procedures?

Tags: delphi

i need a function like the code below (not working! its just example)

```
type
  TCallBack = procedure( x:String) of object;

procedur procA(CallBack : TCallBack);
begin
    CallBack('hello world')
end;
```

and then fire the procA an pass a procedure as parameter:

```
procA( procedure (res : string)
begin
    ShowMessage(res);
end);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your syntax at the CALLING site, it seems like you want to declare the procedure to be called inline at the call site.

If so, you shouldn't use OF OBJECT definition but REFERENCE TO:

```
type
  TCallBack = reference to procedure(x : String);
```

Then you can use your code:

```
procedure procA(CallBack : TCallBack);
begin
    CallBack('hello world')
end;

procA(procedure (res : string)
        begin
          ShowMessage(res);
        end);
```

EDIT: Sample code

```
type
  TCallBack = reference to procedure(x : String);

procedure procA(CallBack : TCallBack);
begin
    CallBack('hello world')
end;

procedure TForm59.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
procA(procedure (res : string)
        begin
          ShowMessage(res);
        end);

end;
```

EDIT: Using the CallBack event from within a thread:

```
PROCEDURE TWebThread.Execute;
  BEGIN
    .
    .
    .
    Synchronize(PROCEDURE
                  BEGIN
                    CallBack('Hello World')
                  END)
  END;
```

But then you have to ensure that any variables you access from within the inline-defined procedure is still valid at the time the thread calls the callback, so don't use local variables, as they may very well have run out of scope. Also, make sure that any CLASS instances you use in the inline-defined procedure hasn't been Free'd or otherwise made invalid between the time you create the thread and the time the callback event is executed.

Comment: Thank you. i tried your code, but access violation error occurred

Comment: if i remove `showMessage(res)` program won't raise error!!!. although working with showMessage is necessary

Comment: It should work as written... Let me check it out, if I have missed something...

Comment: It works fine in my test program... Which version of Delphi are you trying it on? Try making a new VCL Application, and double-click on the form background (to make the FormCreate event), then fill it out as listed above...

Comment: I need this procedure as a completeEvent of a thread. so i pass it  inside the constructor of the thread and fire it on the end of the thread.
` TWebThread.Create(url : String; Params: TStringList; CallBack : TCallBack); `

Comment: @Ahmad: You can't execute a ShowMessage from within a thread. You'll need to use Synchronize to execute the passed-in procedure reference in the main thread.

Comment: @HeartWare Or at least call just `ShowMessage()` itself with `Synchronize()` without syncing the entire callback itself: `Procedure TWebThread.Execute; begin ... CallBack('Hello World'); ... end;` `procA(procedure (res : string) begin ... TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure begin ShowMessage(res); ... end); end);`  It is not always desirable to execute threaded callbacks in the main UI thread. Don't sync code that does not need to be synced, sync only the code that actually needs to be synced.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I didn't know the CLASS method _Synchronize_ of _TThread_, so yes, that's also an option. However, this will put the burden on synchronize or not on the caller and not the callee, so both ways have their uses.